# Text won't left align above list

Tags: spacing, lists, resume

I'm very new to LaTeX and have been using a template from my brother's resume to do up my own, and I have everything exactly how I want it except for the fact that I can't get the text on a line above a list to go all the way to the right.

I have a suspicion that the custom list my brother defines at the beginning of the document has something to do with it but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is the environment set-up he has:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}

\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.30in}}}{\end{list}}
```

and here is two examples of one where I get what I want and one where I don't:

What I want:

```
\textbf{A University} \hfill \textbf{Somewhere} \\
\textit{My position there} \hfill \textit{when 2012}
```

What it looks like:

[image]

What is happening that is annoying me:

```
\textbf{A University} \hfill \textbf{Somewhere} \\
\textit{My position there} \hfill \textit{when 2012}
\begin{list1}
    \item[-] This list messes everything up. 
    \item[-] So unfortunate :(
\end{list1}
```

And it is causing this:

[image]

As you can see `when 2012` has suddenly been almost tabbed over from the right somehow.

If I add a newline after `when 2012 \\` then it will get rid of the 'tab' but put the list down an entire space so I'm hoping there is some simple fix to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second line of your first example is followed by a paragraph break, and the `\hfill` overwhelms the space assigned for the end of the paragraph.

in the second example, the list is begun while you're still in horizontal mode, and there's a space (caused by the normal end-of-line character) between the italic string and the list.

add a blank line before the list and (almost) all should be well.  the vertical space depends on what's assigned for that situation in the document class you're using, but i don't have access to that so i didn't test it.  so you may have to adjust that explicitly, but that's easier than most other methods for dealing with the lack of a flush right line.

as pointed out by Werner in another answer (since deleted), there are quite a few spurious spaces in the definition of `list1`, at the end of every line between `\begin{list}` and `\end{list}`; adding a `%` at the ends of those lines will make this definition better behaved, especially in "edge" circumstances.